# Regex string negation in Fluentd

Tags: regex, parsing, regex-negation, fluentd

I am using Fluentd to parse this line:

```
info=myinfo,details are included here;proc=/usr/;
```

And my parser is this one:

```
(?:info=(?<info>[^,]*))[^\;]+(?:\;)(?:proc=(?<process>[^\;]*))(?:\;)
```

This works fine for matching anything in the "details" field, however, now I want to match only the line if the details do NOT contain the word "Authentication".

I have tried using the regex lookahead approach such as:

```
(?:info=(?<info>[^,]*))^((?!Authentication).)*(?:\;)(?:proc=(?<process> 
[^\;]*))(?:\;)     

(?:info=(?<info>[^,]*))^(?!Authentication).*(?:\;)(?:proc=(?<process> 
[^\;]*))(?:\;)
```

but it does not work. Any idea of how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't check for the comma before the details section, so the negation matches at the comma.

Try the following pattern.  This seems to work here (though it may need refinement).

```
info=(?<info>[^,]*),(?:(?!authentication)[^;])+;proc=(?<process>[^;]*);
```